# Android SQLite retrieve integer

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I fetch a single value from a row in SQLite? for example I have the method getLevel() and a row with "id, coin, level" and the getLevel() is used to get and return the levelonly. How can i do that? Here's my code.

```
public int getLevel(int id) {
    int level = 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT "+colCurrentLvl+" FROM " + userTable + " WHERE " +userID + "="+id; 

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (null != cursor && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        level = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(colCurrentLvl)));
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return level;
}
```

And in my Main Class i need to set it like this.

```
int level = db.getLevel(1);
```

but my emulator force closes. Any help?

```
> 10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidexercises.pics1song/com.androidexercises.pics1song.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.androidexercises.pics1song.DatabaseHelper.getLevel(DatabaseHelper.java:51)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.androidexercises.pics1song.Game.<init>(Game.java:39)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
```

Here is how I initialized the Database and the level.

```
public class Game extends Activity {

DatabaseHelper db;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

            db = new DatabaseHelper(Game.this);
    level = db.getLevel(1);
    }
}
```

Oh and i dont need to add new rows. I just need to update the same row everytime.

Comment: What is `colCurrentLvl`?

Comment: String contaning the column name for my level.

Comment: is it too much to ask to post the actual error and stacktrace ?

Comment: Please include also the context for calling that `getLevel()` function. Where in your code is it, how you initialize `db` and so on.

Comment: Updated with how i initialized my databsae and level.

Comment: ... and the follow-up question: What happens to the Context (`Game.this`) in `DatabaseHelper` constructor - it should be passed to the superclass ctor. And is the exception still the same or something different?

Comment: public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, dbName, null, 1);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
level = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(colCurrentLvl));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229) 10-10 

...

10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): at com.androidexercises.pics1song.Game.(Game.java:39)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-10 11:09:43.626: E/AndroidRuntime(856): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
```

You're trying to initialize an activity class member variable from database too early, e.g. in constructor. But you cannot use the activity as a `Context` until `onCreate()`. Move the member variable initialization to `onCreate()`. And activities should not need explicit constructors anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still force closes.